# Best strategy to render a cursor on mobile/tablet screens?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, mobile, cursor

I was wondering if there was a magic property to make mobile browsers render pointers but can't seem to find one. On desktop, cursor is generated from canvas and exported to CSS cursor property via `url(cursor.toDataURL())`. I'm thinking creating `<img>` cursor element with absolute position every time mouse moves won't be responsive enough. It's pretty flickery even now. What's the best strategy to render cursor on tablets?

- Web app: https://georgegach.github.io/image-color-name/
- Github: https://github.com/georgegach/image-color-name/blob/master/js/script.js#L140

[image]

Comment: Isn't the finger/pen the cursor on touch screens? It would get hidden anyway no?

Comment: Well yes true, but I hoped that huge circle around it would still be usable. Maybe I'll use a different pointer on touchscreen devices though. Will think about a better UI/UX later.

Answer (score 0):

Current better (than canvas rendered cursor) [solution proposed by u/SecondDerivative](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/9sulqw/is_there_a_way_to_show_actual_cursor_on/e8rt9i2) is to use a CSS styled element and follow the pointer movement. Element is created and styled once and only the position+color is changed `onpointermove`. Responsiveness took a hit but it's still pretty usable for such use-case as picking a color.